# how to launch AppLockActivity when we back button click or minmize and maximize app in android

Tags: android

This is my AppLockActivity :

```
public class AppLockActivity extends Activity {
    private Button button;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_lock);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (editText.getText().length() > 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AppLockActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is my MainActvity :

```
public class AppLockActivity extends Activity {
    private Button button;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_lock);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (editText.getText().length() > 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AppLockActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is my Android Manifiest code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="codepath.demos.helloworlddemo"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="codepath.demos.helloworlddemo.AppLockActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

I m trying to make launcher Activity  as AppLockActivity and when we enter some digit then it should go to MainActivity now

1. when we go background to for foreground or when then i have to open AppLockActivity .
2. when we click on device back button then app should close and when we launch then it should start AppLockActivity.

I am trying to add condition using clearActivity function in MainActivity its close app but     android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { flg=0x10008000 }
i am getting this please help me what i am doing wrong please help me to handle  this scenario.

Comment: @Endzeit any idea about could you please suggest me how to handle this